# Are there any unmanaged gigabit switches available without indicator LEDs?

Tags: networking, switch, gigabit-ethernet, led, home-theater

I need to put a switch into my home theatre stack and am looking for something without blinking indicator LEDs. I’ve debated taping over them but that looks ghetto and actually requires some precision taping due to the small size and location of the LEDs.

Has anyone come across an unmanaged gigabit switch—preferably 8 ports—without indicator lights?

As an alternative, does anyone know of a managed switch that has the option to turn off the indicator LEDs?

Comment: slhck: This particular question could have relevance to lots of users as it is a common problem encountered by almost anyone with a home theatre. Additionally, the recommendation for this model of switch will be valid for several years as gigabit is not going anywhere and switches tend to be on the market for several years.

Comment: Kevin, no one is saying your question isn't relevant, interesting or useful. It is, but, based upon the rules of this site, it is still off topic :(

Comment: Black electrical tape can help this issue in many instances...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unmanaged switch with a soft button to turn off all indicator lights (except for power) on the [se2800](http://www.linksys.com/en-apac/products/switches/SE2800). If you turn off the power you will have to hit the soft button again. You will still have to do something about the power indicator but, nail polish works well and can be applied with considerable accuracy.

As for managed switches, seems like certain models have support for changing the LEDs through a web interface and some you need to hook up a serial cable and terminal emulator to alter it from there.

Comment: Thanks m.i! I had been looking through the spec sheets of various different switches with no luck but hadn't come across this Linksys model.

Comment: My SE2500 has the same switch.